# How to ignore @JsonProperty when Serialization in Java

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

json string when deserialization

{"rCode":"1234"}
deserialize to Account

```
public class Account {
    @JsonProperty("rCode")
    private String reasonCode;
}
```

but, when serialize Account to others
like below :

{"reasonCode":"1234"}

How to ignore @JsonProperty("rCode") when Serialization?
or
How to change property name of json when serialization?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Serializing puts it back into object form, no? Can you provide more detail? You show a deserialized format for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple access methods annotated with `@JsonGetter` or `@JsonSetter` respectively, each configured with required name of json property.
In your case the code could be something like this:

```
public class Account {

    private String reasonCode;

    @JsonGetter("reasonCode")
    public String getReasonCode() {
        return reasonCode;
    }

    @JsonSetter("rCode")
    public void setReasonCode(String reasonCode) {
        this.reasonCode = reasonCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    @JsonProperty("1")
    ON, 

    @JsonProperty("0")
    OFF;

    @JsonValue
    fun serialize(): String {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

So this enum will correctly read input values 0, 1 into OFF, ON but after serialization, output values of the object will be OFF, ON still

Answer (score 0):

The BEST solution is using @JsonAlias, it only works for deserialization.

Comment: Since Jackson 2.9

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can amend your own post at any time. So you can extend its content and do not need to comment your own post.